# XAML Binding with dynamically created controls

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have a silverlight application which displays positions of cars on a road.

I am using the MVVM pattern, so i have a collection of MapPosition into my viewmodel.

I am also using an external SDK (from ArcGIS) to do my drawings so the restriction is that i need to draw a Symbol object which contains a TemplateControl in which i can put anything i want of course.

The problem is the i did not find a way to bind a MapPosition object (which basically just contains the coordinates and some additional informations) to the template which i really bad because i have some property that i really need to bind, to change the angle of the icon and to display a tooltip for example.

That is the only way i found to make it work but i really don't like it :

```
        MarkerSymbol symbol = new MarkerSymbol();

        string xamlTemplate = String.Format(@"
            <ControlTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" >
                <Grid Width=""200"" Height=""200"">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=""0.1"" ScaleY=""0.1"" />
                            <RotateTransform Angle=""{0}"" CenterX=""10"" CenterY=""10"" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Canvas VerticalAlignment=""Top"" HorizontalAlignment=""Center"">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content=""{1}""></ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X=""-50""/>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <Path Data=""F1 M 49.75,0L 0,200L 50,158.5L 100,200L 49.75,0 Z"" Fill=""#FF008F00"" Stroke=""Black""></Path>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>", value.Course, value.ToolTip);

        ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate();

        boatSymbol.ControlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xamlTemplate);
```

Then i loop on each elements of my list and create the template on the fly.

So the question is : what is the proper way to bind the template on each objects of my collection and hav the template in the xaml instead of having an ugly string in my codebehind ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
<BoatSymbol.ControlTemplate>
     <ControlTemplate> 
            <Grid Width="200" Height="200"> 
                <Grid.RenderTransform> 
                    <TransformGroup> 
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.1" ScaleY="0.1" /> 
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" CenterX="10" CenterY="10" /> 
                    </TransformGroup> 
                </Grid.RenderTransform> 
                <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"> 
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip Content="{Binding Course}"></ToolTip> 
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip> 
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform> 
                        <TranslateTransform X="-50"/> 
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform> 
                    <Path Data="F1 M 49.75,0L 0,200L 50,158.5L 100,200L 49.75,0 Z" Fill="#FF008F00" Stroke="Black"></Path> 
                </Canvas> 
            </Grid> 
        </ControlTemplate>
</BoatSymbol.ControlTemplate>
```

Assuming that the DataContext of the BoatSymbol is set to the appropriate view model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! But the problem is how can i set the appropriate datacontext for each template. It is easy with a list and a DataTemplate because you specify the ItemsSource but ho is it working if I create my items in the code behind by looping on my collection ?